# php get values from array json output

Tags: php, json

When I use the code below:

```
print_r($jsoni);

$badge_url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid=841370%3Fkey&steamids=76561198108211948&fbclid=IwAR0B4wUlosbqFElHBJw-AkLwb3mGsv42xKdtrEAarDmD97Ur3AprrkW4tCk";

$jsoni = json_decode(file_get_contents($badge_url), true);
```

I get the following as a result:

```
Array
(
    [achievementpercentages] => Array
    (
        [achievements] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => GAME_GREEN_LIGHT
                [percent] => 70.9000015259
)

[1] => Array
(
    [name] => CAREER_EARN_BADGE
    [percent] => 62.2999992371
)
```

How can I get it so that it only shows the name and the percentage?

Comment: Welcome. Please [refer to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), this is extremely basic PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r($jsoni['achievementpercentages']['achievements'])
```

Comment: i think it's a simple decoding that make stdClass!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the decoded data to create an associative array with the achievement names as keys and the percentages as values:

```
$achievements = [];
foreach($jsoni['achievementpercentages']['achievements'] as $achievement)
    $achievements[$achievement['name']] = $achievement['percent'];
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [GAME_GREEN_LIGHT] => 70.9000015259,
    [CAREER_EARN_BADGE] => 62.2999992371
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So im now using the following code.

```
<?php 
        $achievements = [];
        foreach($jsoni['achievementpercentages']['achievements'] as $achievement)
        $achievements[$achievement['name']] = $achievement['percent'];

        print_r($achievements);
?>
```

wich results in

```
Array ( [GAME_GREEN_LIGHT] => 70.9000015259 [CAREER_EARN_BADGE] => 62.2999992371
```

how do i get it to show a list from top to bottom instead of in a cluster of text?
Thanks for the help!